# JSONPATH conditional statement not showing any results

Tags: kubernetes, jsonpath

I'm trying to run a JSONPATH query to pull the IP from a JSON object which is nested within a much larger JSON dataset. I've got to the JSON object containing the IP. However, I want to filter out of all objects to those with a key "type" and the value "InternalIP"

I've tried numerous queries and I keep getting zero results, or all of the JSON spit back at me.

```
controlplane ~ ✖ kubectl get nodes -o=jsonpath="{.items[1].status.addresses[*].[?(@.type=="InternalIP")].address}"

controlplane ~ ➜  kubectl get nodes -o=jsonpath="{.items[1].status.addresses[*].type}"
InternalIP Hostname
controlplane ~ ➜  kubectl get nodes -o=jsonpath="{.items[1].status.addresses[*]}"
{"address":"192.22.69.6","type":"InternalIP"} {"address":"node01","type":"Hostname"}
controlplane ~ ➜  kubectl get nodes -o=jsonpath="{.items[1].status.addresses[*].[?(@.type=="internalip")].address}"
```

I've tried the queries above

Comment: I don't have a cluster to try but, IIRC, try `.items[1].status.addresses[?(@.type=="InternalIp")].address`. The filter (`?()`) applies to the `addresses` slice (`addresses`).